# focusing EditText on HorizontalScrollView causes ScrollView to hide EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, scroll, horizontalscrollview

I have a horizontal scroll view that takes up the right half of the screen. On it, I have an EditText. When I select the EditText to edit the text, the HorizontalScrollView scrolls to the right. I'm guessing it's trying to place the EditText to the leftmost position. Regardless, since the HorizontalScrollView takes up the rightside of the screen, by doing this, I can no longer see the EditText since its now covered up by the contents I put on the left side of the screen. How can I prevent HorizontalScrollView from automatically scrolling when I focus on something inside its layout?

Thanks. Much appreciated.

halp

Edit: Posting code. I'm actually creating my EditText's based off of generated info, so this is not what it actually looks like, but it should capture the ideai.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:layout_leftOf="@+id/Anchor"/>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/Anchor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#000" />

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_rightOf="@+id/Anchor"
            android:fillViewport="true" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp" >

                  <TableRow>
                     <EditText>

                     ABOVE is the view that is going to the left

                     MOre views which would cause Scrolling to the right

                  </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end? I have the exact same problem. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25501869/android-edittext-text-entry-causing-scroll

Answer (score 5):

try this in XML the EditText if use 
         android:gravity="center" 
remove it

Comment: brilliant answer 
never thought this would solve my problem